# participial phrase into subordinate clause

Tags: participles

> Longer life spans mean more people, **worsening** food and housing supply difficulties.

In the sentence above, how can I change the participial phrase ("worsening food and housing supply difficulties") into a subordinate clause?

For example, will "**as it worsens** food and housing supply difficulties" make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Longer life spans mean more people, worsening food and housing supply difficulties.

I reccomend changing the Sentence to;

> Longer life spans **can** mean more people, **thus** worsening food and housing supply difficulties.

Personally your Sentence;

> Longer life spans mean more people, as it worsens food and housing supply difficulties

Doesnt make much sense, your saying a Fact in the beggining, but then relating it to another fact in a rough manner, perhaps try making the second sentence more Comparing in a Cause to Affect form of sentence, which will make it seem more explaining to something else's effects. Yes I know the sentence goes like this:

> Cause & effect, effect

but you want to make it seem more like

> Cause & effect, and effect

(if that makes any sense)